# Issue with jQuery hide() using Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with a `hide()` function on a page I am making.  At the moment, a selected div layer is not hiding.

It all works fine in Safari and Chrome, but unfortunately not in Firefox :-(

The page is here in context: http://www.upreach.org.uk/undergraduates/partners.php and here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('div.partner-employers').not('div#start').hide();
        $("a.employers").click(function(){
            $("a.employers").css("font-weight", "normal");
            $(this).css("font-weight", "bold");
            var myelement2 = $(this).attr("href")
            $(myelement2).fadeIn("fast");
            event.preventDefault();
            $(".partner-employers:visible").not(myelement2).hide();
        });
});
```

...and the HTML:

```
<a href="#1" class="employers">1</a><br/>
<a href="#2" class="employers">2</a><br/>
<a href="#3" class="employers">3</a><br/>

<div class="partner-employers" id="1">Content for 1</div>
<div class="partner-employers" id="2">Content for 2</div>
<div class="partner-employers" id="3">Content for 3</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help that you can give...

Comment: give your elements more meaningful ids than 1, 2, 3. ID's should start with a letter

Comment: @hunter IDs should start but no more 'must' in HTML5. And i said 'should' because CSS still doesn't support IDs starting with a number

Comment: Typically, you should check your console

Comment: In his actual site, the IDs are not numbers.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the comments, had just added a simplified version of the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the undefined `event` variable, so the code crashes before the last line can be executed. In IE this is defined in the `window` object, but not in most other browsers.

Define the `event` parameter in the function signature:

```
$("a.employers").click(function(event){
```

Comment: Perfect, this fixed the problem at the first attempt!

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do:

```
$('.partner-employers').hide();
$(myelement2).fadeIn("fast");
```

Answer (score 0):

change this `$(".partner-employers:visible").not(myelement2).hide();`

into this  `$(".partner-employers:visible").not("#"+myelement2).hide();`